# "There are no whole truths; all truths are half-truths. It is trying to treat them as whole truths that plays the devil"

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is a quote I read in a Wikipedia article entitled "half truth"

What is "it"refering to in this quote

> It is trying to treat them as whole truths that plays the devil.

Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-truth

Comment: The sentence *It is trying to treat them as whole truths that plays the devil* can be rephrased as *Trying to treat them as whole truths is what plays the devil*. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

"It" refers to nothing; it functions as a meaningless syntactic placeholder in the sentence, hence its term—a dummy subject.

The dummy subject is required in a cleft construction where a constituent (i.e. a group of words functioning as a unit) is focused on and the remaining information is put into 'background'. The focal position is immediately after the verb *BE*¹.

> Trying to treat them as whole truths plays the devil — a canonical sentence.
>
> It is **trying to treat them as whole truths** that plays the devil — a cleft sentence where the focus *trying to treat them as whole truth* is highlighted.

---

¹ <sub>Verbs of *BE* are *is, are, was, were, and am*.</sub>

Comment: @AhmadMoustafa Welcome. You can accept this answer if it helps, but I recommend waiting for a day as someone else might come up with a better answer.